# Delete multiple duplicates (ex. same name listed 3 times) in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When I have a list of names and addresses, and the same name and address is listed multiple times, I want to delete all but one of these same names. I have been sorting long lists by last name and deleted duplicates and have always wanted to figure out a formula to do this but haven't found anything.

I need to make sure that the whole row of the duplicate name is deleted. The list has different information in different columns, but I just need one of the same name per row. Maybe some sort of long =if, then formula? or a Vlookup?

Does that make any sense?

Comment: just use Data > remove duplicates (in the data tools group)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for formula, then you may use this.

- I'm assuming that First name are in Col A & Second Name in Col B.

  ```
   =IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1, $A1, $B$1:$B1, $B1)>1, "Duplicate", "")
  ```
- Filter the column for the "Duplicate" & then delete Visible rows.
- Adjust cell references as needed.

**If you are using higher version of Excel then you may use Power Query also.**

- Select the Data Set & from Data tab, hit Get Data then From Table/Range.
- In the Power Query Editor, select the columns containing the first
  and last names,  then Go to the Home tab in the Power Query Editor
  and hit the Remove Rows.
- Then choose Remove Duplicates, then click Close & Load button to
  apply the changes and load the updated data into the Workbook.